# Best way of returning differences of two json files programatically

Tags: php, json, performance, algorithm, comparison

I have two json files and I would like to get a json containing the differences. **It is important** that **only** the actual differences of **content** should be shown, regardless of changing the order of some elements.

What would be the best way to do that? I am searching for a solution as efficient as possible, since `json`s may contain lots of data, and users need jobs to be done as quick as possible.

Note: The `json`s might contain data encoded at different depths. Any programming language is ok, but I would prefer an answer that could easily be implemented in php.

Comment: No matter how you look at it, I believe you just need to go through every single key. Unless you can rely in some kind of identifier but for such thing you will need to elaborate more

Comment: I answered a similar question here: "[Multidimensional Arrays, check difference][1]".  The answer could be modified to descend into branches, if necessary by recursively calling the "get_keys" and "compare_records" methods.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15504734/multidimensional-arrays-check-difference/15504984#15504984

Comment: @J.D.Pace sorry, didn't see it

Comment: "regardless of changing the order of some elements" - I assume you're talking about objects. In lists, order *is* important.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath They are objects gathered from facebook with graph api. I could easily sort them and that wouldn't be a problem anymore, but sorting might cost much time if working with large amounts of data

Comment: @BujancaMihai Hi, Did you succeed in doing this ? i am in the same situation. Any pointers could greatly be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, what you want is something similar to `array_diff_assoc`, but applied to json objects, and recursive.

The `array_diff` functions are not recursive because of reference issues: it is possible to assign a reference of an array to an entry of that array, making the array infinitely recursive. I don't think it is possible to get the same situation with a json object, thus making a recursive function safe.

Let's suppose that you wish to compute the difference between object A and B, and have the result in object C.
The principle is to loop over each field of A (a `foreach` should do), and when:

- no such field exist in B, copy it over C.
- a similar field exist in B, put in C the result of the difference of A field with B field, which is a recursive call on the diff function with those field as parameter, as well as a fresh object for the result.

The ordering of A should be respected.

Comment: Should I rather sort the `json`s?

Comment: @BujancaMihai, notice this algorithm won't consider the keys that only appear in B

Comment: @Alexander that's the principle of set difference: A - B means you want the elements of A not in B. Those appearing in B and not in A are irrelevant.

Comment: @didierc, an edit of the question's title would be appropriate then

Answer (score 9):

Try using [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) function

```
array_diff(json_decode($jsonData1), json_decode($jsonData2));
```

Answer (score 2):

For this task you can try with https://github.com/swaggest/json-diff

It will do key-wise recursive comparison (order of keys does not matter) and produce [JSON Patch](http://jsonpatch.com/) (specified in [RFC 6902](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) from the IETF).