# How to find which one is not common on both JSON using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json, preg-match

I'm writing a script where there will be two data source for notices. One is for main notice source(which is begin scraped from another website). And another is for existing notice source. What I'm trying to achieve is to check the main notice source json titles with existing notice source title. If one notice title is unique in main notice source(that means existing notice source doesn't have that yet), then a function will fire. What I'm trying to do is take one title from main notice source JSON and match that with all titles existing notice source. Here is the code what I've written. But not doing what it supposed to do. :

```
$noticeURL = "https://example.com/scrapper.php";
$existingNoticeURL = "https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=2&per_page=5&fields=title,slug";

$notices = json_decode(file_get_contents($noticeURL), true);
$existingNotices = json_decode(file_get_contents($existingNoticeURL), true);

for ( $i = 0; $i < 5; $i++ ) {
    $notice = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $notices[$i]["title"]);

    for ($j = 0; $j < 5; $j++ ) {
        $existingNotice = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $existingNotices[$j]["title"]);
        if ( $notice != $existingNotice ) {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone can help, that will be great. Thanks for reading... :)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve].

Comment: I'm sorry! I'm a beginner coder! I basically don't know what is the problem is! Tried to explain what I am trying to do, and what happened! I think someone will get the point what I was trying to explain and I believe the solution will be pretty easy too... :)

Comment: This question looks very similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590891/best-way-of-returning-differences-of-two-json-files-programatically . Does that answer your question? If not, what are you looking for that isn't answered there?

Comment: @HPierce That didn't helped! Basically the JSON data on one have depth and another don't have depth. That's maybe the issue I think. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
$noticeURL = "https://example.com/scrapper.php";
$existingNoticeURL = "https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=2&per_page=5&fields=title,slug";

$notices = json_decode(file_get_contents($noticeURL), true);
$existingNotices = json_decode(file_get_contents($existingNoticeURL), true);

for ( $i = 0; $i < 5; $i++ ) {
    $notice = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $notices[$i]["title"]);

    $matchCount = 0;
    for ($j = 0; $j < 5; $j++ ) {
        $existingNotice = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $existingNotices[$j]["title"]);
        if ( $notice != $existingNotice ) {
            $matchCount = $matchCount + 1;
            if ( $matchCount == 5 ) {
                // do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code fixed the issue and achieved the result what I was trying to achieve. Added the count option to track the notice match count. And had to remove the '/\s+/', '' space from this. that fixed the issue. :)