# How can i update a JSON Array in PHP by replacing the old with the new Data

Tags: php, arrays, json, replace

I have a Json-File. In this JSON-File i have deleted an Object. This i reach by creating a new Array and writing this Array to the original JSON-File. But here i get an Issue, cause the new Data overwrite the whole JSON-File.

I tried with

```
array_merge
array_replace
array_merge_recursive
array_replace_recursive
```

But i get always the same Result: (Here i deleted the first Object)

```
{
  "server": {
    "SERVER-01": [
        {
            "svc": "SERVICE01",
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "svc": "SERVICE02",
            "id": 2
        },
        {
            "svc": "SERVICE03",
            "id": 3
        },
        {
            "svc": "SERVICE04",
            "id": 4
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

The original File has this Content:

```
{
  "server": {
    "SERVER-01": [
        {
            "svc": "SERVICE01",
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "svc": "SERVICE02",
            "id": 2
        },
        {
            "svc": "SERVICE03",
            "id": 3
        },
        {
            "svc": "SERVICE04",
            "id": 4
        }
        {
            "svc": "SERVICE05",
            "id": 5
        }
    ]
    "SERVER-02": [
        {
            "svc": "SERVICE01",
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "svc": "SERVICE02",
            "id": 2
        },
        {
            "svc": "SERVICE03",
            "id": 3
        },
        {
            "svc": "SERVICE04",
            "id": 4
        }
        {
            "svc": "SERVICE05",
            "id": 5
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

My Question is, how can i update the Array, for example called Server-01 with the new Data without deleting the other Arrays?

This is the PHP-Code i have so far:

```
// load file
$file = file_get_contents($filename_moni);

// decode copy of json to associative array
$data = json_decode($file, true);

// get ID to delete
$ID = $ID - 1;

unset($data['server'][$Server][$ID]);   

$var=array();
foreach($data['server'][$Server] as $key => $item) {

    $var['server'][$Server][] = $item;      

}

foreach($var['server'][$Server] as $key => $item) {

    if ( $key != $var['server'][$Server][$key]['id'] ) {

        $var['server'][$Server][$key]['svc'] = $item['svc'];
        $var['server'][$Server][$key]['id'] = $key + 1;

    }       

}

$data = array_replace($data,$var);
$jsondata = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT|JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
file_put_contents($filename_moni, $jsondata);
```

Comment: array_diff() function can be helpful?

Comment: Whats `$ID` and `$Server` set to. There is too much code missing from this question

Comment: Thanks.. I found this to array_diff():  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590891/best-way-of-returning-differences-of-two-json-files-programatically  -- Unfortunately it is not usefull to my case.. Any other Ideas?

Comment: $ID and $Server are Variables i get from a Javascript File with Ajax.. I thought it's not relevant to my Question.. so i hadn't write it down. The important thing is, what function i need to update the originale json-file with the new data without overwriting the whole File?

Comment: your 'original' json file is not valid, you have missing comma's (parse errors) on line: 18, 22 and 38.

Comment: So you get as input the `$Server` (in your example `SERVER-01`) and `$ID` (in your example `5`) and you just want to unset it? or you also want to update all other ids on that server? (if you will add desire output to your question we will be more able to help)

Comment: Don't use `$var`, just work on `$data` after the unset. Then write `$data` back to the file. Your `$var` only contains the array you're updating so writing that back will not contain everything

Answer (score 1):

Not having a clear description of the desired output, it seems all you want to do is replace array data with other/updated data... Then something like this suffices:

```
$arr = json_decode($json, true);

// data items to delete
unset($arr['server']['SERVER-01'][0]['svc']);
unset($arr['server']['SERVER-01'][0]['id']);

// the new (dummy) data that needs to be set in lieu of deleted data
$svc = 'SERVICE09';
$id = 9;

$arr['server']['SERVER-01'][0]['svc'] = $svc;
$arr['server']['SERVER-01'][0]['id'] = $id;

// array with inserted values
echo 'array with newly inserted values';
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
echo '</pre>';
```